# Map page load doesn't complete

Tags: google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

Our site works as designed with a minor but irritating problem.  The problem seems to occur only when the page is loaded on Firefox.  I'm using Firefox 17.0.1. On all other tested browsers the load completes.

When loaded, the site displays the map, custom markers and everything else that it is meant to but often the load doesn't complete, there is a message saying "waiting for maps.googleapis.com".  The only effect is the "waiting for" message which is persistent. To refresh the page you have to first cancel the original load and then reload.  Looking at Firebug its appears that a tile isn't completing it's load.  The file that is waiting to complete is always

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i15626&2i7568&2e2&3u6&4m2&1u1507&2u792&5m3&1e4&2b1&5sen-US&token=49261
```

Like I said, minor but irritating - some users have reported the site as broken because they see the persistent "waiting for" message even though everything works as designed.

Even though this may be a Firefox issue, I posted here to see if anyone else is experiencing this and if any solutions exist.

Anything I can to to further explore (or solve) the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are waiting for the map to finish loading before proceeding, make sure you register to the map idle event and not the tilesloaded event.

Comment: Thanks Seain - I'm not actually waiting for any events, my code goes ahead and loads and operates and everything works fine - except that there is this persistent message.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble with Firefox 18.0 on a v3 map page. Working perfectly in other browsers. Just did one of these:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {  
    window.stop();
});
```